# Assitance getting elements from an iFrame using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am clearly being stupid. Please see below and tell me where I am losing it :-(

Html layout

```html
<div class="the-variables">
  <span class="asking">156.25</span>
  <span class="bidding">144.82</span>
</div>
```

iFrame Layout

```html
<iframe id="livetick" style="overflow-y: hidden;" src="http://dev.aatsol.co.za/live-feed/" scrolling="no" seamless onload="window.parent.scroll(0,0);" height="370" width="370" frameborder="0">
&lt;p&gt;Your browser does not support iframes&lt;/p&gt;
</iframe>
```

And this is my javascript attempt

```html
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    
    
    var iframe = document.getElementById('livetick');
    /* var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; */
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('asking');
    //alert (innerDoc.innerHTML);
    //alert (innerDoc);
    console.log(innerDoc);

});
```

For some strange reasons I fail to pull the two values from within the provided spans. They are handled on a remote website fluctuate based on various factors. I simply want to pull them on my website in a iFrame and copy the two values fro inside the iFrame to a section on my website footer.

In short: 
1. Get values inside iFrame
2. Copy exact values to a section on my website footer (using jQuery / javascript)

Comment: Did you look if the console outputs something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the URL of your iframe, you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents cross-origin access to the document. You can't access the DOM of a window that isn't from the same origin as the document you're trying to access it from.

Comment: Thanks @T.J Crowder!! I owe you a beer :-(